# NullReferenceException after catching “A generic error occurred in GDI+.” error for workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I have a strange error after catch the error "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

when i try to open an excel file trought the instruction :

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(FileName);
```

but few minute after catching this exception my application craches (NullReferenceException )without specifying the location of the error !!

knowing that it happens when i try to scan an excel file, but it work for others excel files !!!

I can't locate where the exception with the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is thrown . Visual Studio show that it can't locate it !!!

[image]

So even if i try to handle exceptions in my code i'll have nothing.

Could someone help me in this topic ?

Comment: is the file still opened when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using this approach? And not `xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(....)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Because OP does not use *classic* `Excel.interop` (there is no `LoadFromFile` method) I guess he is using a third party library (Spire.xls) and so it's impossible for us to say what happens.

Comment: @SiddharthRout because im using a third party library (Spire.xls) not Excel.interop

Comment: @ mehow no it was closed.
but the weird thing is that it work for all files i have in my poste unless one !

Comment: i suppose it crashes because the file contains erroneous macro's do you have an idea how to disable macro's?

Answer (score 0):

The TL:DR; version is:

- Something went wrong when the "Generic Error in GDI+" exception was thrown, which you didn't fix in your exception handler (probably because there was no way for you to do so).
- Some time later, something else went wrong as a consequence of the earlier thing.

Long version

***You can only handle exceptions which you know how to handle.***

To handle an exception, as opposed to merely clean up the local variables and re-throw it, you need to fully understand the following:

- Exactly what went wrong
- What **all** the consequences are
- Exactly what needs to be done to put **everything** - all the consequences - right

If you do not know all of those things then you cannot handle the exception correctly.

In your case you have caught an exception (Generic Error in GDI+). However you do not know what caused it, nor how to make sure you have taken care of **all** the adverse consequences it may have caused.

Once you have had an exception you do not fully understand, it is possible that the internal data structures of the application are no longer consistent. For example things might be missing which are otherwise assumed to be present.

If that's the case, it is to be expected that further problems will arise later on, as they have in your case.

Therefore you shouldn't have caught it, or at least should have re-thrown it. It is time for the process to exit, and page the sysadmin to find out what went wrong. Or at least, to start again with a clean slate.

Comment: i suppose it crashes because the file contains erroneous macro's
 
do you have an idea how to disable macro's?